# Show that a matrix is nonsingular

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, trigonometry, determinant, chebyshev-polynomials

What is an efficient way of showing that the matrix 
$$\begin{align}
P\triangleq \begin{bmatrix}\cos\theta_1&\sin\theta_1&...&\cos\theta_n&\sin\theta_n\\
\cos2\theta_1&\sin2\theta_1&...&\cos2\theta_n&\sin2\theta_n\\
\vdots&\vdots&~&\vdots&\vdots\\
\cos2n\theta_1&\sin 2n\theta_1&...&\cos2n\theta_n&\sin2n\theta_n\end{bmatrix}\in\mathbb{R}^{2n\times 2n}
\end{align}$$
is nonsingular for distinct $\theta_i\in(0,\pi)$ (or similar conditions on $\theta_i$).

---

I have seen this [similar post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2619583) but I cannot do the same here. Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: You probably need a stronger assumption than distinctness of the $\theta_i$. At least distinctness $\mod 2 \pi$ is required.

Comment: @HansEngler I agree. The main problem is that, when I want to calculate the determinant using Chebyshev polynomials, I cannot think of any helpful row operations

Comment: For what it's worth, for the case $n=3$ the determinant is $-64 \sin \theta_1 \sin \theta_2 \sin \theta_3 (\cos \theta_1 -\cos \theta_2)^2  (\cos \theta_1 -\cos \theta_3)^2 (\cos \theta_2 -\cos \theta_3)^2$

Comment: @HansEngler Someone told me that if I use Chebyshev polynomials, then by some row operations, I can get a Vandermonde matrix. But I don't see how to do it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $D=\pmatrix{1&1\\ i&-i}$. Then
$$
P(D\oplus D\oplus\cdots\oplus D)
=\pmatrix{
e^{i\theta_1}&e^{-i\theta_1}&\cdots&e^{i\theta_n}&e^{-i\theta_n}\\
e^{2i\theta_1}&e^{-2i\theta_1}&\cdots&e^{2i\theta_n}&e^{-2i\theta_n}\\
\vdots&\vdots&&\vdots&\vdots\\
e^{(2n-1)i\theta_1}&e^{-(2n-1)i\theta_1}&\cdots&e^{(2n-1)i\theta_n}&e^{-(2n-1)i\theta_n}\\
e^{2ni\theta_1}&e^{-2ni\theta_1}&\cdots&e^{2ni\theta_n}&e^{-2ni\theta_n}},
$$
and in turn $P(D\oplus D\oplus\cdots\oplus D)\operatorname{diag}(e^{-i\theta_1},e^{i\theta_1},\cdots,e^{-i\theta_n},e^{i\theta_n})$ is the Vandermonde matrix for $e^{i\theta_1},\ e^{-i\theta_1},\ \ldots,\ e^{i\theta_n},\ e^{-i\theta_n}$.

Comment: Thanks, nicely done. I have a question if you don't mind. Do you think it's possible to get a closed-form expression for the inverse of P in a reasonable amount of time?

Comment: @Mohkam7 There is an explicit formula for the inverse of a Vandermonde matrix. So, $P^{-1}$ is just the Vandermode matrix inverse times the diagonal matrix inverse times the block diagonal matrix inverse.

Comment: Thanks, I see what you mean. I think now I have the formula for the inverse but it looks complicated and not very explicit. I suspect there is another approach to finding the inverse, similar to what you did for the determinant, by guessing some other multiplication matrices.